# Optimize bit reader for ReadInt on datastream

Tags: c#, stream, streaming

Could anyone help me optimize this piece of code?  Its currently a large bottleneck as it gets called very often.  Even a 25% speed improvement would be significant.

```
public int ReadInt(int length)
{
    if (Position + length > Length)
        throw new BitBufferException("Not enough bits remaining.");

    int result = 0;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int off = Position & 7;
        int count = 8 - off;
        if (count > length)
            count = length;
        int mask = (1 << count) - 1;
        int bits = (Data[Position >> 3] >> off);
        result |= (bits & mask) << (length - count);
        length -= count;
        Position += count;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Best answer would go to fastest solution. Benchmarks done with dottrace.  Currently this block of code takes up about 15% of the total cpu time.  Lowest number wins best answer.

EDIT: Sample usage:

```
          public class Auth : Packet
          {
            int Field0;
            int ProtocolHash;
            int Field1;

            public override void Parse(buffer)
            {
            Field0 = buffer.ReadInt(9);
            ProtocolHash = buffer.ReadInt(32);
            Field1 = buffer.ReadInt(8);
            }
          }
```

Size of Data is variable but in most cases 512 bytes;

Comment: Can you at least give some sample input? How big is `Data`? What `length` do you supply in a call to this method?

Comment: How about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: ...in addition, what about the `Length` property?

Comment: What kind of outputs are you expecting? or at least an explanation of what it is you're doing.

Comment: updated.  Length can be 8, 9, or 32

Answer (score 2):

How about using pointers and `unsafe` context? You didn't say anything about your input data, method context, etc. so I tried to deduct all of these by myself.

```
public class BitTest
{
    private int[] _data;

    public BitTest(int[] data)
    {
        Length = data.Length * 4 * 8;

        // +2, because we use byte* and long* later
        // and don't want to read outside the array memory
        _data = new int[data.Length + 2];
        Array.Copy(data, _data, data.Length);
    }

    public int Position { get; private set; }
    public int Length { get; private set; }
```

and `ReadInt` method. Hope comments give a little light on the solution:

```
    public unsafe int ReadInt(int length)
    {
        if (Position + length > Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not enough bits remaining.");

        // method returns int, so getting more then 32 bits is pointless
        if (length > 4 * 8)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        // 
        int bytePosition = Position / 8;
        int bitPosition = Position % 8;
        Position += length;

        // get int* on array to start with
        fixed (int* array = _data)
        {
            // change pointer to byte*
            byte* bt = (byte*)array;
            // skip already read bytes and change pointer type to long*
            long* ptr = (long*)(bt + bytePosition);
            // read value from current pointer position
            long value = *ptr;

            // take only necessary bits
            value &= (1L << (length + bitPosition)) - 1;
            value >>= bitPosition;

            // cast value to int before returning
            return (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test the method, but would bet it's much faster then your approach.

My simple test code:

```
var data = new[] { 1 | (1 << 8 + 1) | (1 << 16 + 2) | (1 << 24 + 3) };
var test = new BitTest(data);

var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                      .Select(x => test.ReadInt(8))
                      .ToArray();
```

`bytes` contains `{ 1, 2, 4, 8}`, as expected.

Comment: This one does not work for me. some examples of usage
  Field0 = buffer.ReadInt(9);
  ProtocolHash = buffer.ReadInt(32);
  Field1 = buffer.ReadInt(8);

Comment: wow, the example is really something... It still does not say anything! I'm 100% sure that using pointers will be much faster than your solution, but unless you ask your questions property, with proper code and usage samples you won't get anything more than my answer.

Comment: Great. Your update says nothing. I can read that method takes `int` from it's declaration. Does it show anything about how `buffer` variable, which is passed as method parameter, is created? How the `BitBuffer` class looks like? What types the properties `Data`, `Position`, `Length` have? Any sample input+output combinations?

Comment: var packet = (BitBuffer)incomingBuffer.ParsePacket();
Packet ParsePacket()
{
  var pack = this.Parse();
  return pack;
}


BitBuffer has those 3 fields and other irrelevant things.

Comment: No point in pasting 3 pages of code here. I just highlighted the hot spot.  What you are asking for is irrelevant unless you want to redes the entire implementation, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I tested this multiple times in different implementations. It just does not work when you read 9 bits. Tho works very well if the amount of bits read is constant 32.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know if this give you a significant improvements but it should give you some numbers.

Instead of creating new int variables inside the loop (*this requires a time to create*) let reserved those variables before entering the loop.

```
public int ReadInt(int length)
{
if (Position + length > Length)
    throw new BitBufferException("Not enough bits remaining.");

int result = 0;
int off = 0;
int count = 0;
int mask = 0;
int bits = 0
while (length > 0)
{
    off = Position & 7;
    count  = 8 - off;
    if (count > length)
        count = length;
    mask = (1 << count) - 1;
    bits = (Data[Position >> 3] >> off);
    result |= (bits & mask) << (length - count);
    length -= count;
    Position += count;
}
return result;
}
```

HOPE THIS increase your performance even a bit

Comment: +0: I don't believe there is any difference between your sample and original code - there should be no penalty for declaring variables each loop vs. outside the loop as compiler+JIT should take care of it... Showing actual numbers would make the answer useful.

Comment: Tested this the compiler just declares ints inside the loop no matter if its debug or release build.